# Flask, not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pythonanywhere

Try to create a register page for my app. I am using Flask framework and MySQL db from [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com).

```
@app.route('/register/', methods=["GET","POST"]) 
def register_page():
try:
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)



    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        email = form.email.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt((str(form.password.data)))
        c, conn = connection()

        x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = (%s)",
                      (email))

        if int(x) > 0:
            flash("That email adress is already in use.")
            return render_template('register.html', form=form)

        else:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                      (thwart(email),thwart(password)))

            conn.commit()
            flash("Thanks for registering!")
            c.close()
            conn.close()
            gc.collect()

            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['email'] = email

            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template("sign-up.html", form=form)


except Exception as e:
    return(str(e))}
```

On running I get the Error:not all arguments converted during string formatting.
How to fix it? May be the problem in this statement?

`c.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                          (thwart(email),thwart(password)))`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the error is happening at that line?  I think the problem is more likely to be at the x = c.execute() line above, where you should have `(email,)` -- note the trailing comma -- as the last parameter, not `(email)` with no trailing comma.

Comment: I changed `(email)` to `(email,)` and got the same result

Comment: It worked! I just didn't restart the server. Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just converting my earlier comment to an answer, as it seemed to be the right solution :-)

The problem is coming from a different line.  You have this:

```
        x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = (%s)",
                      (email))
```

This doesn't do what you might think it does.  Putting `email` in brackets does nothing, so the line is actually equivalent to passing in each character of whatever's in that variable in a list of characters.  If instead you do this:

```
        x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = (%s)",
                      (email,))
```

...then you'll be passing in a tuple containing one item, `email`, and it should work better.